# Erro - string C# para o Crystal Report

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

Ao tentar passar a string do c# Windows Forms para o Crystal Report seguindo o procedimento da segunda imagem e do código abaixo o crystal report mostra o seguinte erro! Visual Studio Community 2017, Mysql free e Crystal Report Sap.

Erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
    cryRpt.Load("C:\\Users\\Rafael\\Desktop\\ProG\\Gold Business - Another\\Gold Business\\CrystalReport1.rpt");

    ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions;
    ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition;
    ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
    ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = usuario;
    crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
    crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["usuario"];
    crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

    crParameterValues.Clear();
    crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
    crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);

    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
    crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
}
```

Ligando no Crystal Report:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: que linha está estourando a exceção? é em "crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["usuario"]; "  ?

Comment: crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["usuario"];    // aponta esta linha

Comment: O mais provável é que você não esteja passando o nome, no caso "usuario", correto, se eu fosse você colocaria um breakpoint aí e daria uma olhada na collection de crParameterFieldDefinitions pra ver se encontra o nome de fato do seu campo

Comment: desculpe eu sou novato com o Crystal Report, como devo passar no parâmetro a "string" usuario para fazer conexão com o código escrito acima deve ser aí o erro, está passando no parâmetro, no crystal report, na segunda imagem abaixo.

Comment: cara, sinceramente é mais fácil fazer o que eu falei, se você abrir a collection lá vai dar pra ver o nome dos seus parâmetros corretamente, mas se não me engano acho que precisa por uma @ antes do nome do parâmetro, talvez seja só isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que pode substituir todo esse código de atribuição de um parâmetro por isto:

```
cryRpt.SetParameterValue("usuario", "Eu!");
```

Após essa substituição pode inclusive deixar de lhe dar erro, isto se o parâmetro realmente existir no *report*.

Comment: Dá o mesmo erro! e aponta para esta linha cryRpt.SetParameterValue("usuario", "Eu!")  no caso só tem no Crystal Report o parâmeto "usuario" no caso como eu deveria passar o parâmeto está como na segunda imagem acima.